# Does trace of Ricci squared test for Ricci-flattness?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

Assume a Euclidean space with signature $(+,+,+,+...)$

If we know $R_{ab}R^{ab} = 0 $ does this imply $R_{ab}=0$ ?

And if so, will this test fail in Minkowski space with mixed signature?

We know $\sum_{ab} R_{ab}R_{ab}=0$ defines ricc-flatness since it is just the sum of the squares of the components.

Comment: Counter example: Null dust solutions for Einstein fields equations will satisfy $R_{ab}R^{ab}=0$

Comment: @KP99 the question is about euclidean signature.

Comment: @Javier It doesn't matter. Any smooth manifold will admit Riemannian metric (+,+,+,...). Also OP asks if the test applies to Lorentzian metric

Comment: In Euclidean signature, yes, since in an orthonormal frame $R_{ab}R^{ab}=R_{ab}R_{ab}$. In Lorentzian signature, no. It is possible to have nonzero Ricci tensor whose square is zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the signature is all plus signs, then given any point $P$ you can choose locally flat coordinates, such that the metric at $P$ is $\delta_{ab}$. This means that at that point $R_{ab} R^{ab} = \sum_{ab} R_{ab} R_{ab}$, which by your argument means that $R_{ab} = 0$ in these coordinates and at $P$. But $P$ was arbitrary, and if a tensor is zero in one coordinate system, it's zero in any system. Therefore, in Euclidean signature $R_{ab}R^{ab} = 0$ implies $R_{ab} = 0$.